# Extracting Twitter username from a given text (JAVA, Regex)

Tags: java, regex, twitter

I believe the code is OK, the problem is the regex.

Basically I want to find a username mention (it starts with @), and then I want to extract the allowed username part from the given word.

For example if the text contains "@FOO!!" I want to extract only "foo", but I believe the problem is with my "split("[a-z0-9-_]+")[0]" part.

Btw, allowed symbols are numbers, letters, - and _

```
public static Set<String> getMentionedUsers(List<Tweet> tweets) {

    Set<String> mentioned = new HashSet<>();

    for (Tweet tweet : tweets) {
        String tweetToAnal = null;
        if (tweet.getText().contains("@")) tweetToAnal = tweet.getText();
        if (tweetToAnal == null) continue;
        String[] splited = tweetToAnal.split("\\s+");
        for (String elem : splited) {

            String newElem = "";
            if (elem.startsWith("@")) {
                newElem = elem.substring(1).toLowerCase().split("[a-z0-9-_]+")[0];
            }

            if (newElem.length() > 0) mentioned.add(newElem);
       }

    }

    return mentioned;

}
```

Comment: IIRC, the Twitter api will provide @mentions within a Tweet's metadata. Are you not using the API?

Comment: Or use a proven `"@(\\w+)"` regex.

Comment: using `(?<=@)[\w-]+` shoult be sufficient, you wouldn't neet to split or anything...

Comment: @rmlan No, I can't use the API, the tweets are in text format already.

Comment: @nozzleman can you provide more code? I'm trying mentioned = (Set<String>) Arrays.asList(tweet.getText().split("?<=@)[\\w-]+")); (also I believe you missed one \ before w), but it isn't working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not on your regex but on your logic.

You are using below line to analize usernames:

```
if (elem.startsWith("@")) {
    newElem = elem.substring(1).toLowerCase().split("[a-z0-9-_]+")[0];
}
```

If you debug step by step your code, you will notice that you are consuming (with `substring(1)`) the `@` and then you are splitting by using a regex, therefore this split is consuming all your characters as well. However, you don't want to **consume** characters with the `split` method but you just want to **capture** content.

So, you can actually use split by using the negated regex you are using by doing:

```
split("[^a-z0-9-_]+")
        ^---- Notice the negate character class indicator
```

On the other hand, instead of splitting the whole text in multiple tokens to further be analyzed, you can use a regex with capturing group and then grab the username you want. So, instead of having this code:

```
String[] splited = tweetToAnal.split("\\s+");
for (String elem : splited) {

String newElem = "";
if (elem.startsWith("@")) {
    newElem = elem.substring(1).toLowerCase().split("[a-z0-9-_]+")[0];
}

if (newElem.length() > 0) mentioned.add(newElem);
```

You can use a much more simpler code like this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=@)([\\w-]+)").matcher(tweetToAnal); // Analyze text with a regex that will capture usernames preceded by @

while (m.find()) { // Stores all username (without @)
    mentioned.add(m.group(1));
}
```

Btw, I didn't test the code, so I may have a typo but you can understand the idea. Anyway the code is pretty simple to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java-Person, but you can easily match twitter-usernames without the "@" using the following regex:

```
(?<=@)[\w-]+
```

which [can be seen here](https://regex101.com/r/A8OR9E/1). Of course you would need to escape special characters properly, but since I have no clue of Java, you would have to do that and the actual matching by yourself.